# Grouping two columns with values to get a third column

Tags: python

you'll find two columns Name and N - for most entries both name and N are same

but there are cases where N is missing when Name is present and vice versa

Group the columns such that k I have one resultant column that has all values

Example :

```
Col1 Col2 value.... 

Adam   nan   334

John    nan   56

nan    Michael  90
```

Result :

```
Col1 value.... 

Adam   334

John    56

Michael  90
```

Comment: What if the two names differ?

Comment: is this pandas?

Comment: The two names won't differ, the problem has the same names @alkasm

Comment: Pandas, Yes @Valentino

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows() :
  if not isinstance(df['col1'][index],str) : 
    df['col1'][index] = df['col2'][index]
```

knowing that nan is a float, if it finds that the value at 'col1' is nan it will take the value at 'col2'

or using apply

```
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['C'] if not isinstance(x['B'],str) else x['B'] ,axis= 1)

new_df = df.delete('C',axis=1)
```

Comment: Type error : string indices must be integers @nassim

Comment: i updated my answer, please check it i hope it helps